# Jenkins pipeline plugin how to run parallel tasks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins pipeline plugin how to run parallel tasks

I am a beginner in jenkins, I want to launch few tasks in parallel on available slave nodes of jenkins using pipeline plugin.

I installed pipeline plugin and added below in the pipeline inline script section.

```
grovvy script : 
    parallel firstBranch: {
        node('master'){
            echo 'firstBranch'
        }
    }, 
    secondBranch: {
        node('slave1'){
            echo 'secondBranch'
        }
    }
```

***NOTE***: master and slave1 are my nodes

What are firstBranch and secondBranch ideally ????

Console output:

> Started by user anonymous
>   [Pipeline] parallel
>   [Pipeline] [firstBranch] { (Branch: firstBranch)
>   [Pipeline] [secondBranch] { (Branch: secondBranch)
>   [Pipeline] [firstBranch] node
>   [firstBranch] Running on master in /scratch/gnithyan/.hudson/workspace/pipeline_test
>   [Pipeline] [secondBranch] node
>   [Pipeline] [secondBranch] // node
>   [Pipeline] [secondBranch] }
>   [secondBranch] Failed in branch secondBranch
>   [Pipeline] [firstBranch] {
>   [Pipeline] [firstBranch] echo
>   [firstBranch] firstBranch
>   [Pipeline] [firstBranch] }
>   [Pipeline] [firstBranch] // node
>   [Pipeline] [firstBranch] }
>   [Pipeline] // parallel
>   [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>   
>  java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot start writing logs to a
>   finished node
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepStartNode[id=8] at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.LogActionImpl.(LogActionImpl.java:110)
>   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.LogActionImpl.stream(LogActionImpl.java:81)
>   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.DefaultStepContext.get(DefaultStepContext.java:73)
>   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(StepDescriptor.java:252)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:179) at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126) at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
>   at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$0.call(Unknown Source) at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)

Comment: please format the code (remove html content)

Comment: I just starting getting this on a previously working pipeline script w/ the latest version of Jenkins as well.  Haven't figured out what the stack dump means yet :-(

Comment: In the below grovvy script 

1.what does firstBranch and secondBranch signifies???

2.does master and slave1 should be always the name if the available nodes on jenkins??

 grovvy script    :     
 parallel firstBranch: {
node('master'){
echo 'firstBranch'
}
}, secondBranch: {
node('slave1'){
echo 'secondBranch'
}
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem. Perhaps I found the depending plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Supporting+APIs+Plugin
See Release Note for Version 2.10
Regression in log handling with certain steps inside parallel in 2.9.

**Yes updating the PlugIn works!**

Comment: Updating Pipeline Supporting APIs Plugin to version 2.10 worked. Thanks!! All

Comment: Yes sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in pipeline api Version 2.9 and will be fixed with 2.10 (see also the release notes https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Supporting+APIs+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks perfectly correct. I had my delivery defined as a pipeline and it worked fine. Today, after updating Jenkins from 2.25 to 2.26 I got the same error. Downgrading to 2.25 didn't help, though, perhaps because I have updated plugins as well :(